# Having trouble center entire navigation menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, centering

I'm having trouble centering a very simple menu on a very simple Wordpress site. I'm only at an intermediate level, in terms of CSS and I cannot find the functionality to center the menu (not the individual menu text elements...the whole menu container). I've tried a number of remedies proposed in other threads, like changing the float to none and nothing seems to be working. What am I missing? TU

https://www.lyndenmusicfestival.com/

Comment: To tell you, what you are missing, we need to see, what you have. Please show us your code.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) You have to add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: I appreciate that link...However, I am unsure of which code has the issue so I can't add it to my question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Even without seeing the code, lets try something simple that works quite often:

Give the menu a `margin: 0 auto;`

That tells the menu to have automatic space left and right. If that isn't working try giving the menu a `display: inline-block;` -- careful, the margin auto won't work if the menu itself is `display: block` without a width. So use either 'inline-block', or 'block' with defined width.